# How to group JSON data by value using Angular ngFor?

Tags: angular, typescript, grouping, ngfor

I have the following JSON:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "workT": "001",
      "workTypeDesc": "Test 1",
      "id": "1",
      "jobNr": "0003",
      "jobDesc": "Header 1",
    },
    {
      "workT": "003",
      "workTypeDesc": "Test 2",
      "id": "2",
      "jobNr": "0002",
      "jobDesc": "Header 2",
    },
    {
      "workT": "001",
      "workTypeDesc": "Test 1",
      "id": "3",
      "jobNr": "0001",
      "jobDesc": "Header 3",
    }
  ],
  "result": null
}
```

I have to group this data according to `workT` and `workTypeDesc`. That is, to appear grouped according to the image (and [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-accordion-demo-cvacps?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)):

[image]

Comment: You can iterate on all element and add them into a map which contains a list of object for a workT

Comment: Please can you implement something, I'm not clear. Thnx

Comment: I will try to do something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the data can be transformed in several ways to fit as a source for the UI component you would like to use. One alternative is to simply map the `data` array to an object with one attribute/key for each group of arrays of corresponding `workT` value.

The data transformation as such has nothing to do with angular, as that is a standard Javascript data manipulation:

```
grouped = yourJsonData.data.reduce((group, current)=> {
//create your grouping key, by which you want to group the items
const groupingKey = `${current.workT} - ${current.workTypeDesc}`;
//if the group does not yet have an entry for this key, init it to empty array
group[groupingKey] = group[groupingKey] || [];
//add the current item to the group
group[groupingKey].push(current);
return group;
}, {})
```

Here we take the `data` array, and use [js reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to convert it to an object, where keys correspond to unique values of `workT - workTypeDesc` and value is the array of items that have that `workT` as value.

This you can then pass to any angular directive to render as nested element e.g.

```
<p-accordion>
    <p-accordionTab header="{{group.key}}" *ngFor="let group of grouped | keyvalue">
        <p-accordion>
            <p-accordionTab header="jobNr:{{item.jobNr}} - jobDesc:{{item.jobDesc}}" *ngFor="let item of group.value">
                <pre>{{item | json }}</pre>
            </p-accordionTab>
        </p-accordion>
    </p-accordionTab>

</p-accordion>
```

Here we use the `keyvalue` pipe from angular that allows iteration over object keys(by default ngFor only allows iterable as source).

[Demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-accordion-demo-efzmzb?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can do to parse it :

```js
// define function that will manage it
var groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};

let valueToGiveToNgFor = groupBy([
{
  "workT": "001",
  "workTypeDesc": "Test 1",
  "id": "1",
  "jobNr": "0003",
  "jobDesc": "Header 1",
},
{
  "workT": "003",
  "workTypeDesc": "Test 2",
  "id": "2",
  "jobNr": "0002",
  "jobDesc": "Header 2",
},
{
  "workT": "001",
  "workTypeDesc": "Test 1",
  "id": "3",
  "jobNr": "0001",
  "jobDesc": "Header 3",
}], 'workT'); // 'workT' is by you want to groupBy values

  console.log(valueToGiveToNgFor);
```